# Dynamically Selecting Role in Membership Provider

Tags: c#

I have 3 Roles in Membership Provider such as:

- PRINCIPAL
- TEACHER
- STUDENT

A single User may have both "PRINCIPAL" and "TEACHER" Role.
Soon after,that particular user (who have the 2 Roles) Logged In, I got Bind all roles in a RadioButtonList for that User.

Now, He want to select one Role after Logged In and My Home Page should be for that particular Role of that User.

How to assign Role for the User dynamically?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the Membership API from Microsoft you can assign role like this

```
Roles.AddUserToRole("UserName", "RoleName");
```

[Click here for further informations](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647401.aspx#paght000013_step3)

Comment: Actually What I'm trying to ask is..

"HttpContext.Current.User = new GenericPrincipal(id, role);"
This code assigns the role for that User in that Particular page where we are using the above code..
But I need to have that in all pages. What code should i replace for it..?

Comment: If you are implementing your page due to the [MVVM-Pattern](http://aspnetmvvm.codeplex.com/), you are able to provide this functionality in the base class of your model. The other way is to include a script in every page, which overrides the page_load function.